# Using NUnit to test that an IEnumerable was sorted correctly (uses nested sort)

Tags: linq, sorting, tdd, nunit, mvp

I'm using MVP with ASP.NET Web Forms. Being a good TDDer, I want to test all the important behaviors in my Presenter, including the default sort it applies to the result set retrieved from the service layer.  The Presenter will be applying a nested sort via LINQ to Objects of the style:

```
public IEnumerable<ViewModel> MyModel{
   get
      {
          return _myService.GetResults().OrderBy(r=>r.PropertyA).ThenBy(r1=>r1.PropertyB);
      }
}
```

I've looked at the IsOrderedBy extension method described [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082624/isorderedby-extension-method), but I'm not sure how to extend it to work with the nested sort I describe above.
Ditto for the code posted by Jon Skeet in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301822/how-to-sort-an-array-of-object-by-a-specific-field-in-c/1302185#1302185).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unit testing I use to be as explicit as possible. Let your mock service return a list with some items with different values for PropertyA and PropertyB. Then manually sort that list into a "right answer list". Finally compare with `.SequenceEqual<>`.